# Maximum number of markers in a cluster in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

Using the Leaflet.markercluster plugin, is there a maximum amount of markers that can be added to a cluster group?

I only ask as I display a cluster of ~13000 markers just fine, but then using the same code when trying to display 100,000+ markers in a cluster it just doesn't display.

The shows it can display 50,000 no problem but I can't find any mention of displaying a higher amount of markers.

Comment: What do you mean by "it just does not display"? Is the browser saying that the script takes too long? In that case use the `chunkedLoading` option. In theory there is no limit, but it takes much longer time to compute. Try also a re-built version of markercluster (see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/593), as it is now much faster.

Comment: @ghybs the outline of the map displays but it stays empty - which happens when I make other errors. I have tried with chunked loading as well. I will have a look at this re-built plugin, thank you :)

Comment: I just tried with 150k and no problem.

Comment: Now I'm confused as when I drastically cut down on the number of markers they all display. I loop through a JSON file and add them to a marker cluster.

Comment: Could be the JSON parsing that struggles with big file. Could you try splitting your file and load by small pieces?

Comment: Just realised that there were extra speech marks in some of the names of entries in the JSON! Removed all of them and now the browser is saying the script takes too long, with chunkedLoading turned on. Thanks for your help! I will try and split the JSON file :)